# Email Count in Zimbra

Tags: automation, zimbra

In our office we use Zimbra and we have a little administrative problem.

Every Monday our secretary has to manually create an email in which the number of emails is shown for every user. She has to log into the admin account, look at the inboxes of every user, count the emails and then write the number down manually.

Although we're a rather small company It's still really time consuming and now we're looking for an easier way to do this.

Can you automate this task either via Zimbra itself or an app/plugin of Zimbra? Or would we have to write one ourselves?